# In HTML, how can I make a control take up all the horizontal space of the left column without going to the next line

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to be a good developer and not use tables, but I've been unsuccessful.  Here's my attempt...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Because some people complain if I don't specify all the obvious tags</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width:100%">
        <div style="background-color:Purple;width:25px;float:right"><input type="button" style="width:15px" /></div>
        <div style="background-color:Aqua"><input style="width:100%" /></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the output that I get.  I was hoping the input box would be on the left side of the button, but unfortunately it's underneath.

[image: Output]

To demonstrate what I want, this is how I would do it if I were to use a table:

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td style="background-color:Aqua"><input style="width:100%;box-sizing: border-box" /></td>
        <td style="background-color:Purple;width:25px"><input type="button" style="width:15px" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[image: Expected output]

Please note:

- I can't change the doctype tag
- The solution must not use tables
- This should work regardless of the size specified in the containing div, which is currently set to 100%.

Thank you :)

Comment: I suggest you mention to whomever required that doctype that it's old and not recommended. `<!DOCTYPE html>` is cleaner, far easier to remember, and is the latest doctype. Your page isn't even XHTML, so that particular doctype is an especially poor choice.

Comment: I know <!DOCTYPE HTML> is for HTML 5, but this is quite old, large site I'm working on and I don't want to mess things up.  By the way... why do you say my page isn't XHTML?

Comment: First of all, HTML5 is backwards-compatible. Anything that breaks with that switch (and I highly doubt anything will) shouldn't have been coded that way in the first place. I suggest you try it. And it's not XHTML because you don't have the correct MIME Type meta tag. Basically every browser ever ignores the XHTML doctype when it can in favor of the MIME type. It's just parsing it as HTML.

Comment: I should mention that I misspoke somewhat: while browsers will treat a text file without the MIME type set as HTML, regardless of what the doctype says, the MIME type can be set in the server as well as in a meta tag. I could not know, from looking at your code, whether or not your server was configured to do so, though the fact that you didn't know what I meant suggests that it wasn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I had a working table layout as you do, I'd do something like this:

```
.layout-table
{
    display: table;
}
.layout-table > div
{
    display: table-row;
}
.layout-table > div > div
{
    display: table-cell;
}
```

And then:

```
<div class="layout-table" style="width:100%">
    <div>
        <div style="background-color:Aqua">
            <input style="width:100%;box-sizing: border-box">
        </div>
        <div style="background-color:Purple;width:25px">
            <input type="button" style="width:15px">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yWD8D/11/)

Of course, all that styling would be done externally too, but you get the point. This is identical to your table layout, but it's done with divs styled to act like tables, separating layout from content.

Actually, I would probably be lazy and just use `<table role="presentation">` but that's bad (not to mention invalid with your obsolete doctype).

Answer (score 2):

When you float an element using CSS you take it out of what is called the "document flow". So basically what is happening here, is the aqua colored box is actually extending behind the yellow box. See: http://jsfiddle.net/hegvz/ . The result is that the width of the aqua box is actually more than what is visible, so the input extends to fill the entire width of the rendered box.

You have a couple of options to fix this:

1) Add a padding to the side of the non-floated box equal to the width of the floated box, plus whatever white space you would like. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/QVpnw/ . You will see the aqua box still extends behind the yellow box, but the input of the aqua box is now shortened properly.

2) Add a margin to the side of the non-floated box equal to the width of the floated box. This will result in the aqua box rendering white space, instead of color. You will also want to adjust the padding in this case. http://jsfiddle.net/SVKr6/